# install CMAKE error linuxmint

Tags: gcc, cmake, ld, linux-mint

I'm trying to install CMAKE On linuxmint 16, but I get errors.
I have gcc.

The errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld cannot find crt1.o no such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld cannot find crti.o no such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld cannot find crtn.o no such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Test failed to compile
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Install it from Software Manager. There are no problems.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Installing from software manager did not solve the problem for me, I needed to install libc6-dev package manually.

Answer (score 0):

This command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```